# How to solve Jenkins npm command not found error?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to run a vue project on jenkins.I have installed nodejs on my server.But I got an error below:
`SSH: Connecting from host [manager.cweap.eap] SSH: Connecting with configuration [10.168.1.222] ... SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms SSH: Disconnecting configuration [10.168.1.222] ... SSH: Transferred 0 file(s) ERROR: Couldn’t find any executable in "/home/eap/cweap/node-v14.18.1-linux-x64/bin" Finished: FAILURE`

Any help would be very helpful.